# How add polyline to mapbox.js map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, drawing, polyline, mapbox

I'm using [mapbox.js map javascript api](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v0.6.5/) but I didn't found native methods to creating lines, polylines, polygons and etc. I founded one [example](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/vectors-with-d3/) which probably can help me, but it look difficult.

I use mapbox, because it support greatest [map animation](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v0.6.5/#Easing) that I know. See [example](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/optimal-easing/).

Who know easy examples or libraries which provides drawing lines, polylines and etc with mapbox.js api?

Answer (score 3):

mapbox.js doesn't currently support line-drawing itself, but you can [use it with d3](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/vectors-with-d3/) to support polylines.